# Multiple conditions to track all clicks with Google Analytics

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I'm trying to track all links clicked with Google Analytics as events.  So I wrote some jQuery to capture that. I'm just starting with jQuery, so I don't know if I'm doing it the most efficient way so I'd like some feedback or suggestions as to how to improve the code.  The simpler and faster it is, the better, as it is tracking analytics.

**EDIT: Here's the latest code.  I can't figure out why the last button and 3rd to last return undefined values. 
http://jsfiddle.net/uqj88/**

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
      var pageURL = window.location.pathname;
      var linkText;

      $('a').click(function (e) {
          if ($(this).text() != ""){
                linkText = $(this).text();
          }
          else if (($(this).text() === "") && ($(this).children("img") != "") && ($(this).children("img").attr("alt") != "")) {
                linkText = $(this).children("img").attr("alt");
          }
          else if (($(this).text() === "") && ($(this).children("img") != "") && ($(this).children("img").attr("alt") === "")) {
                linkText = $(this).children("img").attr("src").split("/").pop();
          }
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', pageURL, 'click', linkText]);
          if (($(this).attr('target') != '_blank') || ($(this).attr('target') != '#')) {
                e.preventDefault();
                setTimeout('document.location = "' + $(this).attr('href') + '"', 150);
          }
      });
      $('button').click(function () {
          linkText = $(this).text();
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', pageURL, 'click', linkText]);
      });
      $("input[type='submit']").click(function () {
          if ($(this).attr("value") != ""){
                linkText = $(this).attr("value");
          }
          else if (($(this).attr("value") === "") && ($(this).prop("id") != "")) {
                linkText = $(this).prop("id");
          }
          else if (($(this).attr("value") === "") && ($(this).prop("class") != "")) {
                linkText = $(this).prop("class");
          }
          else {
                linkText = "button";  
          }
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', pageURL, 'click', linkText]);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your example.  I believe that in newer versions of jQuery (like 1.7+), it is recommended that you not use the `attr` method.  I tested that by using the `prop` method and it now works:  http://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/uqj88/3/

Also, I know this was sample code but it seemed strange that you used the `var` declaration before each use of `linkText`, I think that messes up the scope of the variable a bit.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep that helps a ton, thanks!  I changed some things slightly, and swapped the alerts with the google tracking code.  I added the updated code in the main post.  Does it all look good? Nothing weird?

Comment: I think it looks ok, heck I'll probably borrow it for a site or two :)

Answer (score 2):

Just an FYI that can save you some analytics headaches... `_trackPageview` and `_trackEvent` work by requesting a tracking pixel from Google. If you leave the page before the request has had a chance to complete, you'll end up with inconsistant data. The event may or may not get counted, depending on a number of things you don't have control over.

One way of handling this is to delay following the link by a small amount (150 ms in this case) if the link doesn't open in a new window.

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    <snip>
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', pageURL, 'click', linkText]);
    if ($(this).attr('target') != '_blank') {
        e.preventDefault();
        setTimeout('document.location = "' + $(this).attr('href') + '"', 150);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I'll keep this in mind and add it to the final code.

Comment: Hey Mike, I'm trying to use this piece of code you provided, but I added a part to it that also says OR if href is # (like onclick javascript links and so on).  But when I add my part, it doens't respect target _blank of links anymore and it opens them up in the same window.

`if (($(this).attr('target') != '_blank') || ($(this).attr('href') != '#')) {`

Comment: Logic error -- for target==_blank links is href!=#?
Maybe something like
`if (!($(this).attr('target') == '_blank' || $(this).attr('href') == '#')) {`

Comment: Ahh you're the man!  That fixes it.  I didn't think it was a logic error though.  I guess I need to study and research more into logic.  Thanks!